# What is AsyncPipe and examples to use

Tags: angular, pipe

I need your help. I'm trying to study the angular in more detail and got to asyncPipe. I have this example, but I don't know how it works. Can you please explain how this code works in detail? Thank you very much

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
    <p *ngIf="($observable | async) as time">
  Current Timer Value {{time}}
    </p>`,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{'

$observable: Promise<any>

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.$observable = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('foo')
    },3000)
  });
}

}
```

Comment: If you want to display the value of a variable, like `age`, you just display it with `{{age}}`. Now, if the age is given in an `Observable<number>` instead of a `number,` you display it with `{{ $age | async }}`. This is the main usage of the async pipe. Of course, you could also subscribe to the `Observable` and extract the given value but the async pipe will do this for you

Comment: I really hope this example is not from some kind of official angular course..

Comment: @MikeOne No, i took it from site

Comment: It’s quite a bad example.. riddled with mistakes. I’d look for a different source of information to be honest? Angular.io is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms `async` pipe subcscribes to an observable, "unpacks" its data and takes care of unsubscribing. It is considered better practice than manually calling `.subscribe()` and in `ngOnDestroy()` calling `.unsubscribe()`.

When we use `async` pipe we don't have to worry about above mentioned things.

In your example you faked an API call in `ngOnInit` lifecycle method and you want to display data you got from that call in `.html` file. Additionally, this `as` in your template just makes a template variable that you used below.